# What is the step by step solution from $((10-4y)/3)^2+y^2=5y$ to this: $y^2-5y+4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My book says that the solution is $y^2-5y+4=0$ to this $((10-4y)/3)^2+y^2=5y$ problem but somehow i cant calculate it to that solution. Is this exercise correct? If yes what are the steps to the solution.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). We want to know what you have tried.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Both equations have the same roots, but don't define the same curve over all $y$.

$$y^2-5y+4 = (y-1)(y-4) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow y \in \{1,4\}$$
Now,

$$\left(\dfrac{10-4y}{3}\right)^2 + y^2 = 5y \iff \dfrac{100-80y+16y^2}{9}+y^2=5y$$
$$\iff$$
$$100-80y+25y^2=45y \iff 25y^2-125y+100=0 \iff y^2-5y+4=0$$

so we see the solutions are the same, namely $y=1$ or $y=4$.